# R: Efficient construct a matrix from a vector and fill it with certain conditions

Tags: r

I would like to construct a matrix `A` according to a vector `k` such that everywhere `A_ij` is the minimum of `k_i` and `k_j`.

Currently, I can do it as follows:

`k <- c(3, 1, 6, 5)`

`mm <- outer(k, k, function(x, y) ifelse(x <= y, x, y))`

But, if the vecor is large, the code I wrote run relatively slow, how can I improve the computational efficent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to speed things up by an order of magnitude:

```
outer(k,k,pmin)
# or if you are only dealing with integers and speed reeaaaly matters:
outer(k,k,pmin.int)

identical(outer(k,k,pmin), outer(k, k, function(x, y) ifelse(x <= y, x, y)) )
#[1] TRUE

k <- 1:5000
system.time(outer(k, k, function(x, y) ifelse(x <= y, x, y)))
# user  system elapsed 
# 6.21    0.52    6.73 
system.time(outer(k,k,pmin))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.51    0.03    0.54 
system.time(outer(k,k,pmin.int))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.48    0.03    0.51
```

Comment: could use pmin.int in this case to be more efficient

Comment: why would you accept an answer that is literally 1000 times slower than my answer? And creates a table that is n times as large, which is a huge unnecessary waste of memory...

Comment: @hedgedandlevered: the result is 'n' times as large as yours because that's what the OP asked for.

Comment: @hedgedandlevered, can you get the same answer with `k <- c(3, 1, 6, 5)

mm <- outer(k, k, function(x, y) ifelse(x <= y, x, y))`, which is 4-by-4 matrix. Sure, If only opterating the upper triangle or lower triangle, it can improve efficient.